# Help with php loop

Tags: php, foreach

i need to extract data from this array of objects

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "136104923104306",
            "from": {
                "name": "GetWith.It",
                "category": "Website",
                "id": "136132969751208"
            },
            "message": "Do u know y **LOVE IS BLIND**\nbcoz..\n''ur mom started to love u before seeing ur face''....!",
            "updated_time": "2010-10-05T13:41:42+0000",
            "comments": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "136104923104306_1075253",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Hressence Ec",
                            "id": "1464305271"
                        },
                        "message": "this I would agree..love is surely blind..",
                        "created_time": "2010-10-12T01:40:47+0000",
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

My current code:

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://myurl/where/this/data/is'));
foreach($data as $dts){
echo "$dts->message";
};
```

i need to extract the comments ..
and when i try

```
foreach($data->comments->data as $dts){
echo "$dts->message";
};
```

it returns null!
help please

Comment: I don't think your data is "json-valid" btw.

Try validating it on http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: `NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.` http://pt2.php.net/json_decode

Comment: Btw: You should "take a look" at your $data with var_export, print_r or whatever, to "see" the problem. You could also work with a debugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$data` is actually an object with a *data* property that is an array containing another object with the *comments* object you are looking for. So:

```
foreach ($data->data as $item) {
    foreach ($item->comments->data as $comment) {
        echo $comment->message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you transform it into an associative array:

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://myurl/where/this/data/is'), true);
```

and have a look at the structure.

I think your loop must look like this:

```
foreach($data['data'] as $dts) {
    echo $dts['message'];
}
```

**Update:** Although I was able to fix the JSON (at least it seems to be good now) `json_decode` still returns `null`. No clue way. First make sure your JSON string is valid!